# "*.so" linked library can't open it's shared object file

Tags: c++, cmake

I am building project using some libraries and CMake.
There are two projects; first is library using *.so" file and second is library and executable based on the first.

But when I run executable file of second project,
I get the following error:

```
my_library: error while loading shared libraries: my_lib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

CMakeLists.txt of FirstProject:

```
add_library(my_lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET my_lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION lib/my_lib/my_lib.so)

add_library(my_first_lib SHARED my_first_lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_first_lib my_lib)
```

CMakeLists.txt of SecondProject:

```
add_library(my_second_lib my_second_lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_second_lib ${my_first_lib_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(my_second_exe my_second_exe.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_second_exe my_second_lib)
```

How to link "*.so" file properly?

Comment: Are they build together as sub-project?

if not, try export the library path your 1st project use with:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="PATH TO THE FOLDER CONTAIN YOUR LIBRARY"

Comment: If, instead of the relative path `lib/my_lib/my_lib.so`, you use an *absolute* path, does it find the library then?

Comment: @UyTrieuViTran If I add that variable, "my_lib.so.0" is detected but other libraries are lost. In my case, I use ROS lib, so I get following error "libroscpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Unfortunately, your method is not working for me.

Comment: @kyungpyokim in the folder your LD_LIBRARY_PATH (assuming that you have exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH) is pointing to, try put all of your dependencies into that folder (libroscpp.so for example).